# How to restructure an Object in C# using LINQ?

Tags: json, linq, group-by, c#-3.0

I have a data set as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Country": "Uruguay",
        "Name": "Foo",
        "Status": "Completed",
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Country": "Uruguay",
        "Name": "Foo",
        "Status": "Completed",
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Country": "Germany",
        "Name": "Foo",
        "Status": "Completed",
    },
]
```

I want to transform and sort it by Country so that it looks as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Country": "Uruguay",
        "Details": [
         {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Foo",
            "Status": "Completed",
         },
         {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Foo",
            "Status": "Completed",
         },
        ],
    },
    {
        "Country": "Germany",
        "Details": [
         {
            "Id": 3,
            "Name": "Foo",
            "Status": "Completed",
         },
        ],
    },
],
```

These are the classes in C#:

```
public class Countries {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Details {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class CountryList {
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<Details> Details { get; set; }
}
```

Some of what I have tried looks as followed:

```
var foo = countries
    .GroupBy(x => new Details { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, Status = x.Status })
    .Select( y => new CountryList 
     {
         // Country = y.Key. 
     }

var foo = countries
    .GroupBy(x => x.Country)
    .Select( y => new CountryList 
     {
         // Country = y.Key.
         Details = y.GroupBy(a => new Details 
         { 
            Id = a.Id, 
            Name = a.Name, 
            Status = a.Status  
         }).ToList() 
     }
```

I am having trouble working out how to use LINQ to solve this. I have done a handful of GroupBy operations in the past, but I wasn't able to work this one out. How do I transform my dataset into the desired result?

Comment: It sounds like you want to group by just the country name. Constructing a Details object inside the group by doesn't make sense.

Comment: In what you have tried, it's correct to group by Country, then project (`Select()`) into a CountryList, but then Details looks like it should be another projection, not a group by: `Details = y.Select(a => new Details { ... })`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need second GroupBy

```cs
var foo = countries
    .GroupBy(x => x.Country)
    .Select(y => new CountryList 
     {
         Country = y.Key,
         Details = y.Select(a => new Details 
         { 
            Id = a.Id, 
            Name = a.Name, 
            Status = a.Status  
         }).ToList() 
     };
```

Comment: A simple Linq Query gets 4 upvotes and an accepted. StackOverflow rep system is really weird. When you help someone for 2 hours you usually get nothing :o

Comment: @Charles, agree with you, it is weird. I have a lot of really complicated answers  with zero reaction.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the [`.GroupBy()` overload that lets you define a  `resultSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-1-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-2)))) to create your `CountryList`s and populate their `Details`:

```csharp
var countries = new List<Countries>
{
    new() { Id = 1, Country = "Uruguay", Name = "Foo", Status = "Completed" },
    new() { Id = 2, Country = "Uruguay", Name = "Foo", Status = "Completed" },
    new() { Id = 3, Country = "Germany", Name = "Foo", Status = "Completed" },
};

List<CountryList> countryList = countries
    .GroupBy(
        c => c.Country,
        ( country, matches ) => new CountryList()
            {
                Country = country,
                Details = matches.Select(match => new Details 
                    { 
                        Id = match.Id, 
                        Name = match.Name, 
                        Status = match.Status 
                    }).ToList()
            })
    .ToList();
```

, `( country, matches ) => new CountryList() { ... }` being the `resultSelector`.

---

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ANp7V5).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var orig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Countries>>(json); 

List<CountryList> countries = orig.GroupBy(o => o.Country)
.Select(x => new CountryList {
Country = x.Key,
Details = x.Select(o => new Details {Id=o.Id,Name=o.Name,Status=o.Status} ).ToList()
}).ToList();
```